# After logging in and downloading cookies using --cookie-jar, how do we use the downloaded cookies to access the page again?

Tags: wget, curl, cookie

I used the command below to download cookie using CURL in bash. How do I use this file (cookies.txt) to access the page?

```
curl -u username --cookie cookies.txt --cookie-jar cookies.txt https://example.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `curl` command is correct. With the `--cookie cookies.txt` option, you reuse the cookies that were previously saved with the `--cookie-jar cookies.txt` option.

With `wget`:

```
wget --load-cookies cookies.txt --save-cookies cookies.txt ...
```

Comment: It only download the cookies.txt. I am not able to see the output of curl. Nothing is printed to stdout.

Comment: Update your question with the precise URL your are probing so that we can reproduce your problem and see what happens. BTW, cookies.txt is not downloaded at all, it a local file that is updated with the cookies that come along with the content you are downloading.